# How to Get Optimal Jpg Quality Value To Make File As Small As Possible?

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, jpeg

I want to make batch resizing thousands of jpg images application in C# for website.
For high quality resizing I have found the answer in other question.
But I want the result **files size is as small as possible without reducing quality significantly**.

```
EncoderParameter qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, quality);
```

**How Can I determine or calculate the optimal Quality value of jpg in Bitmap class?**

============
Edit 1:
Maybe software like smush.it, pngout, pngcrush etc are the examples. I want to know how they define the optimal quality.

============
Edit 2:
Like Oli and haraldK: May be my clearer question is:
How can I define Quality value based on standard deviation?
For example if a color is from 0 to 255, my threshold deviation is 25.

Comment: Define "optimal quality".

Comment: Surely this is a design/developer or even business choice? You need to decide what quality level is correct and then adhere to your decision. The problem you'll face is each graphic type is typically better at certain types of graphics (.gif not doing gradients as well as ping, where as .jpg doesn't support transparency)

Comment: @Oli, that what my question is, how to define optimal quality. Because every image has different quality value to get optimal image quality.

Comment: @Dave, I have seen a lot of image optimization software to get as small as possible image with acceptable quality. I want to know what kind of algorithm to define the optimal quality.

Comment: Optimal in terms of what?  If you want minimum distortion, then you need to maximise quality, and vice versa.

Comment: Optimal quality means as high compression as possible but quality is still acceptable. For example, for white blank image, we can use simply 0 for quality. But for high detail image quality must be around 90%. I want to automate that.

Comment: "Optimal quality means as high compression as possible but quality is still acceptable." - Now you just have to define "acceptable"... :-P

Comment: @HaraldK, it must not be from my definition. Probably there are a standardization and algorithm to write the code. That what I want to know. I don't know also whether Wikipedia or Wordpress are already used that to create thumbnail. Or they just use fix quality.

Comment: @YohanesNurcahyo You don't seem to get the point. If you can't say what is "acceptable", how can you know when you have found the "high[est] compression as possible but quality is still acceptable"? For that you have to define "acceptable" in some way or another.

Comment: @haraldK, maybe I can say quality can be calculated using standard deviation between the original image with the compressed one. If the byte range per color is 0 to 255 then let me say I want the standard deviation is 25. So I want the algorithm to calculate the quality value to get more and less standard deviation 25.

Comment: Then, see my answer below.

Comment: I found that 30% is generally the lowest you can make the jpeg quality without the result being visibly damaged. It's the lowest for which I could still stand to look at the resulting image, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, you should be able to write out an image, starting at a high quality setting, and then successively again at lower quality settings, until you go below your "acceptable" threshold. Keep the one at lowest quality above your threshold (this "algorithm" can be optimized, similar to binary search).

To automatically test for "quality", you could compute the percentage difference in pixel values between the compressed image and the original, and compare it against your threshold value. The threshold value would have to be found by trial and error.

Unfortunately, the human eye will not agree with this algorithm in many cases, as there will always be parts of the image that draws attention and will be more important, variance in certain colors are more important than others, etc, etc.. Image "quality" is a very subjective thing.

So, I semi-agree with @Olivier's answer:

> No, you can't.

But go ahead and try. Be creative, maybe you find something that works for you. :-)

Comment: Yes, you are correct, this similar algorithm is already written in ImageMagick but the threshold is the file size. For small file it is okay, but for more than 100.000 files and high resolution maybe it is very expensive. Maybe if I know what the meaning of quality in the compression algorithm, that will help me.

Comment: You should probably state in your question that you know about this algorithm, and why it doesn't work for you. :-) The meaning of JPEG "quality" varies between different software. It's not in the algorithm. But you should probably read up on the JPEG format in general to get an idea of what parameters you can adjust (chroma subsampling, quantization tables, DCT process etc.), that will affect quality.

Comment: yes, maybe I will use your algorithm because I realize that I save the files after resizing it to much smaller size, so the speed is not the problem anymore. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. The higher the compression factor, the worse is the image quality and vice versa. Choosing parameters is always a compromise and depends only on your subjective judgment of the result.

Test different settings and take the one you prefer.

Comment: Yes I know if smaller file the quality is worst. I want to know how to get the optimal value, because I think every image has different quality value. For example for high detail images must have high quality value to prevent lost detail.